# IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions> contains empty options when HandleAuthenticateAsync() is called

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I've created my own authentication handler in ASP.NET Core MVC v2.0.

It is invoked OK, but the options object is empty when the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method is invoked.

**Startup config**

```
authenticationBuilder.AddSingleSignOn("SingleSignOn", options =>
{
    options.OpenGlobalDb = () => OpenGlobalConnection(configuration);
    options.OpenTenantDb = orgId => OpenTenantDb(configuration, orgId);
    options.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies";
});
```

*(I've had a breakpoint in the code and it's invoked)*

**The authentication handler**

```
public class SingleSignOnAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<SingleSignOnAuthenticationOptions>,
    IAuthenticationRequestHandler
{

    private IOptionsMonitor<SingleSignOnAuthenticationOptions> _options;

    public SingleSignOnAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<SingleSignOnAuthenticationOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // _options.CurrentValue.OpenGlobalDb is null here.
    }

    //[.. all other methods ..]
}
```

**Auth builder extensions**

```
public static class AuthenticationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddSingleSignOn(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, string authenticationScheme, Action<SingleSignOnAuthenticationOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        return builder.AddScheme<SingleSignOnAuthenticationOptions, SingleSignOnAuthenticationHandler>(authenticationScheme, "SingleSignOn authentication", configureOptions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not save an own version of the `options` object in the constructor. Use the `Options` property in the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. There seems to be so little documentation about this.